# Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'UILabel *' is disallowed with ARC

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I got a compiling error "Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'UILabel *' is disallowed with ARC" in the code below.

```
UILabel* (^makeLabel)(CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat, NSString*) = ^(CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat w, CGFloat h, NSString* title) {
    UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);
    label.text = title;
    label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    return label;
};

UILabel* lblEmail = mekeLabel(30, 100, 100, 30, @"이메일");
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to define the return type explicitly everywhere, like:

```
UILabel * (^makeLabel)(CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat, NSString *) = ^UILabel *(CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat w, CGFloat h, NSString * title) {
    UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);
    label.text = title;
    label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    return label;
};
```

then this will work flawlessly:

```
UILabel * lblEmail = makeLabel(30, 100, 100, 30, @"이메일");
```

Comment: It is not necessary to define the return type explicitly for block, see this link for more details  https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html. The problem is that there is a typo `mekeLabel(30, 100, 100, 30, @"이메일");`.

Comment: @RomanPodymov, OP needs to define the return type explicitly. full stop.

Comment: The following code does not produce a warning: `UILabel* (^makeLabel)(CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat, NSString*) = ^(CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat w, CGFloat h, NSString* title) {UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] init];label.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);label.text = title;label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];return label;};UILabel* lblEmail = makeLabel(30, 100, 100, 30, @"이메일");lblEmail.text = @"이메일";`. The problem was in calling `mekeLabel(30, 100, 100, 30, @"이메일");`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your code. You should call `makeLabel(30, 100, 100, 30, @"이메일");`. The reason why you get this error is that `mekeLabel` is perceived as a block that is declared later. Blocks in Objective-C return `int` by default.